# How to assign the function button for Bracketing in Nikon D7000

Tags: nikon-d7000

For my Nikon D7000, instead fumbling each time for exposure bracketing setting, is there a way to assign this to the function button in front of the camera thereby I can press this button and shutter release button together to get bracketed images ?

Answer (score 4):

[image: Bracketing button on D7000]

The D7000 already has a bracketing button (shown in the image above) on the left side, above the lens mount.
While keeping this button pressed, you can rotate the front and rear command dials to configure the exposure value (± EV) and the no. of frames.

You can then switch the shutter release to CL (continuous low) or CH (continuous high) to take multiple bracketed shots for an HDR (if that's the intent).

Hope this helps.